# How do I draw a class diagram where theres two user modes which is decided upon login and each user mode have different interfaces

Tags: java, swing, class-diagram

So basically I am supposed to create a gui swing project about an inventory and sales management system. So I have multiple interfaces where I can add products and manage stocks and stuff. So the first interface is login which requires the user to select either admin or director. Admin has similar interface and same functionality as director but director has 3 extra interfaces which the admin dont have. So I already have a class called login with attributes username, password and method login(). Idk how do I proceed after this because of the confusion about the two modes.

So I tried creating a class each called admin and director and my mind just fell blank. I dont know how to proceed since both of them have a couple of similar interfaces with the same functionality. (Only the design part is different for them). I tried and tried and Im just stuck here. So I have other interfaces like add products, view stocks etc which is included in both the modes with the only difference being the design. Idk how to draw a class diagram for this.

Comment: start with the inventory - that's your data model. I'm not sure you need a separate sales management class; instead, you need functionality for moving products in and out which maybe you could define through interfaces. Finally, give your admin and director the proper interfaces for the functionality they should have

Comment: I wouldn't have a separate Login class - you can use a JPanel with JOptionPane to get login information, or you could use this: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/dialogs/ParamDialog.java

Comment: I don't understand why not just have a User class with an admin/director attribute.

Comment: But then how do I deal with different interfaces between the admin and director after having an user class with an admin/director

Comment: That's a different question.  Create a `JFrame` with a main `JPanel` using a `CardLayout`.  Create `JPanels` for both the admin and director.  Show the admin `JPanels` for the admin and the director `JPanels` for the director.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.